# Spring mapping Handler doesn't map my curl request to a method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am making my first RESTful app and currently have a problem that Spring mapping handler doesn't map properly (when executing curl, get 404 Not Found). Here is my code:

CURL: curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/restaurant-voter/rest/restaurants

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">

    <display-name>Topjava</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/spring-app.xml
            classpath:spring/spring-db.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Spring-mvc.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.vadimmazitov.**.web"/>

<!--  all resources inside folder src/main/webapp/resources are mapped so they can be referred to inside JSP files -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<bean class="ru.vadimmazitov.voter.web.json.JacksonObjectMapper" id="objectMapper" factory-method="getMapper"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <!--                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">-->
            <!--                    <list>-->
            <!--                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>-->
            <!--                        <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>-->
            <!--                    </list>-->
            <!--                </property>-->
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver "/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="conversionService">
    <property name="formatters">
        <set>
            <bean class="ru.vadimmazitov.voter.web.converter.DateTimeFormatters.LocalTimeFormatter"/>
            <bean class="ru.vadimmazitov.voter.web.converter.DateTimeFormatters.LocalDateFormatter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/restaurants", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RestaurantRestController {

    private final Logger log = getLogger(getClass());

    private RestaurantService service;

    @Autowired
    public void setService(RestaurantService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List < Restaurant > getAll() {
        log.info("get all restaurants");
        return service.getAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity < Restaurant > create(@Validated(View.Web.class) @RequestBody Restaurant restaurant) {
        log.info("create {}", restaurant);
        checkNew(restaurant);
        int userId = SecurityUtil.authUserId();
        Restaurant created = service.create(userId, restaurant);
        URI uriOfNewResource = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
            .path("/rest/restaurants/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(created.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uriOfNewResource).body(created);
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@Validated(View.Web.class) @RequestBody Restaurant restaurant, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        log.info("update {} with id {}", restaurant, id);
        assureIdConsistent(restaurant, id);
        int userId = SecurityUtil.authUserId();
        service.update(userId, restaurant);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Restaurant get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        log.info("get restaurant with id={}", id);
        return service.get(id);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>
        4.0.0
    </modelVersion>
    <groupId>
        vasyapupkin
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>
        graduation
    </artifactId>
    <version>
        1.0-SNAPSHOT
    </version>
    <packaging>
        war
    </packaging>
    <name>
        Voter
    </name>
    <url>
        http://voter.herokuapp.com/
    </url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>
            11
        </java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>
            UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            UTF-8
        </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring.version>
            5.1.7.RELEASE
        </spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>
            5.1.5.RELEASE
        </spring.security.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>
            2.1.9.RELEASE
        </spring-data-jpa.version>
        <spring-context.version>
            5.2.0.RELEASE
        </spring-context.version>
        <tomcat.version>
            9.0.22
        </tomcat.version>
        <jackson-json.version>
            2.9.10
        </jackson-json.version>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <hibernate.version>
            5.4.3.Final
        </hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>
            6.0.17.Final
        </hibernate-validator.version>
        <javax-el.version>
            3.0.1-b11
        </javax-el.version>
        <!-- Tools -->
        <ehcache.version>
            3.7.1
        </ehcache.version>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>
            1.2.3
        </logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>
            1.7.25
        </slf4j.version>
        <!-- Testing -->
        <junit.jupiter.version>
            5.5.1
        </junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>
            topjava
        </finalName>
        <defaultGoal>
            package
        </defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>
                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    maven-compiler-plugin
                </artifactId>
                <version>
                    3.7.0
                </version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>
                        ${java.version}
                    </source>
                    <target>
                        ${java.version}
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven -->
                <groupId>
                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    maven-surefire-plugin
                </artifactId>
                <version>
                    2.22.1
                </version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.slf4j
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                slf4j-api
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${slf4j.version}
            </version>
            <scope>
                compile
            </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                ch.qos.logback
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                logback-classic
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${logback.version}
            </version>
            <scope>
                runtime
            </scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hsqldb
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hsqldb
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.4.0
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.fasterxml.jackson.core
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                jackson-databind
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${jackson-json.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                jackson-datatype-hibernate5
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${jackson-json.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                jackson-datatype-jsr310
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${jackson-json.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- - ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hibernate
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hibernate-core
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${hibernate.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hibernate.validator
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hibernate-validator
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${hibernate-validator.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hibernate
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hibernate-jcache
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${hibernate.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.glassfish
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                javax.el
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${javax-el.version}
            </version>
            <scope>
                provided
            </scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                javax.cache
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                cache-api
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.1.0
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.ehcache
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                ehcache
            </artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
            <version>
                ${ehcache.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-context-support
            </artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${spring-context.version}</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework.data
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-data-jpa
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${spring-data-jpa.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-webmvc
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                5.1.5.RELEASE
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.tomcat
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                tomcat-servlet-api
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${tomcat.version}
            </version>
            <scope>
                provided
            </scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework.security
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-security-web
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${spring.security.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework.security
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-security-config
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${spring.security.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework.security
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-security-taglibs
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${spring.security.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.junit.jupiter
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                junit-jupiter-engine
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${junit.jupiter.version}
            </version>
            <scope>
                test
            </scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>
                    org.springframework
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    spring-framework-bom
                </artifactId>
                <version>
                    ${spring.version}
                </version>
                <type>
                    pom
                </type>
                <scope>
                    import
                </scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You did nothing wrong with your code, it comes from the Tomcat web server or IDE.
Let's say you're using Tomcat when you deploy a war file ( ex: **restaurant.war**) it will automatically extract to folder **restaurant** and the context path will be ***/restaurant***.
You expect your context path is **restaurant-voter** but it was **graduation** by following current code

> We can simply rename the war file is `restaurant-voter.war` to fix your problem.

I'm using IntelliJ. If you also use it, you can change config like image below, *other IDE should be similar*.

[image]
*[UPDATED BASE ON CURRENT SOURCE CODE]*

Comment: added "/restaurant-voter" as url pattern, still get 404

Comment: Could you please give me the source code somewhere like Github?

Comment: https://github.com/VadimMazitov/restaurant_voter.git -- it's a bit messy at the moment, but mapping should still work in my opinion

Comment: I found the reason. I'll update you on the answer, it's a bit long.

Comment: Since the problem has nothing to do with the code i delete my answer :D @Tea NG please enjoy my upvote :)

Comment: (y) . Happy coding, friends

Answer (score 0):

can you check either spring-mvc.xml file is present under the folder WEB-INF/spring/spring-mvc.xml because in your dispatcher servlet context config location you have mentioned

spring-mvc.xml under the folder name called spring.